# How can I flash the BIOS on a Dell T5500?

Tags: dell, bios

I been given a Dell T5500 Workstation that used to be maintained by a gentleman that no longer works at the company I work for. The workstation has a BIOS admin password as well as a BIOS boot password that are not the same. I know the boot password because I used the machine prior to him leaving but failed to get the admin password from him.

I need to install a new OS on the workstation, but I'm not given the option to boot from CD before or after the BIOS boot password prompt. I assume this is because the option was either disabled in the BIOS or because it's not presented when theres a BIOS boot or admin password present. I figure my only way around this is to flash a new BIOS on the workstation which is probably a good idea since I currently have no way to make changes to the existing BIOS.

What's the process for flashing the BIOS on a workstation such as this? Is a floppy drive needed (this machine doesn't have one)? Is it even possible if I don't have access to the current BIOS settings?

Comment: I know I focus on the fact that the machine's a T5500 when flashing a BIOS likely depends more on the specifics of the motherboard, but I failed to gather the motherboard info before leaving the office today. I won't be back into the office until Monday, but wanted to go ahead and post now in hopes that folks would have a chance to answer over the weekend.

Comment: Most Dells have a jumper on the main board to clear the BIOS settings.

Comment: Cool, I'll look Monday to see if I can locate such a jumper...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dell Precision T5500 has jumpers specifically for clearing passwords.

From the [Dell Precision™ T5500 Service Manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/wsT5500/en/SM/a_sysbd.htm):

[image]

Jumpers (#3) PSWD and RTCRST_PSWD.  Also from the service manual the [Clearing Forgotten Passwords](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/wsT5500/en/SM/a_sysbd.htm#clear_pw) section details how to perform the reset:

> 1. Remove the computer cover.
> 2. Locate the 4-pin password connector (PSWD) on the system board.
> 3. Remove the 2-pin jumper plug from pins 3 and 4 and set the jumper plug aside.
> 4. Replace the computer cover.
> 5. Connect your keyboard and mouse, then connect your computer and monitor to electrical outlets and turn them on.
> 6. After the operating system loads, turn the computer off.
> 7. Disconnect the keyboard and mouse, then disconnect the computer and monitor from their electrical outlets.
> 8. Press the power button on the computer to ground the system board.
> 9. Remove the computer cover.
> 10. Replace the 2-pin jumper plug onto pins 3 and 4 of the password connector (RTCRST_PSWD) on the system board.
> 11. Connect your computer and devices to electrical outlets, and then turn them on.

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks jscott! I'll try this out on Monday and post my results here as an update.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling the CMOS battery (it generally looks like a shinny coin) should reset the BIOS to a default state. You'll lose the [TPM Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module), so backup everything you'll want to before you do this *if* something is using the TPM, e.g. BitLocker. (Though this doesn't sound like an issue for your particular case.)

Once you've done that you'll have to flash the [New BIOS](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=R318808) using an external floppy drive. We have a couple USB2 floppy drives we use of cases like this.

If that's not an option you can use something like [HP Drive Key](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=US&swItem=MTX-UNITY-I23839&mode=4&idx=2) to load the BIOS update onto a USB drive. (You'll have to make an appropriate Windows/DOS environment on them.)

**EDIT:** It looks like the BIOS can be updated from your existing OS, so you can probably disregard the floppy trickery. I was looking at a different and earlier set of Dell T5500 BIOS updates. (You may still have to reset the CMOS, though I suspect that the Flash will just overwrite the existing BIOS without doing any form of security check.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide all this info! If I reset the BIOS to a default state by pulling the CMOS battery, will that get rid of the BIOS admin and boot passwords? If so, then I probably wouldn't need to flash the BIOS correct? Or will some other BIOS setting that doesn't get reset still keep me from being able to boot to CD so I can install the new operating system?